# How can I overlap patterns in a Venn diagram legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern, venn-diagrams

I've drawn a Venn diagram using `tikzpicture`, with different patterns filling the different circles. I've also used a `matrix` to draw the diagram's legend off to the side. It's easy enough to create legend entries for the non-overlapping portions of the diagram, because they only use one pattern. But how can I specify two overlapping patterns in the legend to indicate the overlapping areas of the diagram?

My code so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,patterns,positioning,svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  1/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=north east lines},
  2/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=north west lines},
  3/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=vertical lines},
  4/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=dots}
  ]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=venn]
      \fill[1] (135:1) circle (2);
      \fill[2]        ( 45:1) circle (2);
      \fill[3]        (-90:1) circle (2);
    \end{scope}
    \matrix [draw,right=1em of venn]{
      \node [1,label=right:1] {}; \\
      \node [2,label=right:2] {}; \\
      \node [3,label=right:3] {}; \\
      \node [4,label=right:4] {}; \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can probably guess, the fourth entry in the legend is supposed to refer to the center of the diagram, but I substituted `dots` because I could not figure out how to overlap all three patterns.

Comment: using colors is better I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `postaction`s to superimpose patterns. I added

```
\node [1,postaction=2,label=right:$1\cup 2$] {}; \\
```

to illustrate this. You can have more than one `postaction`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,patterns,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  1/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=north east lines},
  2/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=north west lines},
  3/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=vertical lines},
  4/.style={shape=rectangle, pattern=dots}
  ]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=venn]
      \fill[1] (135:1) circle (2);
      \fill[2]        ( 45:1) circle (2);
      \fill[3]        (-90:1) circle (2);
    \end{scope}
    \matrix [draw,right=1em of venn]{
      \node [1,label=right:1] {}; \\
      \node [2,label=right:2] {}; \\
      \node [3,label=right:3] {}; \\
      \node [4,label=right:4] {}; \\
      \node [1,postaction=2,label=right:$1\cap 2$] {}; \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. The colors are automatically mixing due to the option `[opacity=.5]`.
[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.5]
\fill[red] (135:1) circle (2);
\fill[blue] (45:1)  circle (2);
\fill[cyan] (-90:1) circle (2);

\path (4,0) node[matrix,draw]{
\node[fill=red,label=right:A] {}; \\
\node[fill=blue,label=right:B] {}; \\
\node[fill=cyan,label=right:C] {}; \\
\node[fill=red!50!blue!50!cyan,label=right:G] {}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```